# Why dynamic link is not working on ios device when app is in running/background state?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

I have implemented firebase dynamic links to my flutter App. In android device every thing is working fine but in ios device dynamic link work only when App is in killed state. It is not working when app is in running state.I click dynamic link when app is running then it does not take me to desired location in my app. It simply opens up the screen which was opened before clicking the dynamic link.
I am using firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.0.In this version two methods are provide that are

1. getInitialLink a future to retrieve the link that opened the app.

2.onLink a callback to listen to links opened while the app is active or in background.

I have no idea why it is not working on ios device?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you got the solution for this, I have same issue